# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException : Android

Tags: java, android

I am working on my first Android application and I have a question about icons.

I have created layout files and directories called mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-ldpi etc.

mipmap-hdpi contains the icons, but I have not stored different size icons in mipmap-ldpi etc.
Now when I try to run the application, I am getting the following exception: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException.

Is it necessary to have to provide all icons in all folders ?
If we have stored it in only one folder then it should not take from it ?

Comment: in my case i just remove de folder **mipmap-anydpi** and the issue has gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not have to specify different resources to different sizes. you can put your icon inside the Drawable folder and it will work.
Of course this is not recomended, and you have many tools to create all icon sizes. my favorite is Android Asset Studio: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

> its necessary to we have to provide all icons in all folders ?

**No**, it's not required

But You should use **drawable-dpi** folder to place image for supporting multiple screen, see official [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

**mipmap/folders** are use to place your launcher icons

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand your question, you want to use some images in your app. for this you only have to copy and paste your images under res->drawable

and also if you want to have your images in mipmap folder, there is one directory under res->mipmap.
just use that, you don't need another directory for your images.

and the last part of your question:
no there is no need to have different size of picture.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use different size images for different android devices we need to create different drawable or midmap folders like

```
drawable-mdpi , drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi 

    or 

midmap-mdpi ,midmap-hdpi, midmap-xhdpi, midmap-xxhdpi 

and then put different images with different folder based on sizes.
```

Otherwise We can create one main folder name like drawable or midmap folder and put images with that folder. It will use that images for all devices.

But you cannot use only one folder with image like drawable-hdpi like that. It will support only hdpi devices not for all devices because of this problem its throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

This will work every android without any exceptions!

1. Take your **png** file inside `mipmap-xxxhdpi` folder
2. Put it to https://www.img-bak.in/ site.
3. Then you can generate drawable files. Export downloaded zip file
4. Move the res folder into android project's res folder.

Now you can use the icon as `@drawable/ic_launcher_round` in your **xml**